# Fastest public elevator in the world

Tags: sightseeing, factoids

[The Main Tower](http://www.maintower.de/en/observation-deck-more/main-tower-from-a-to-z/) is my favorite attraction in Frankfurt am Main not only because of the wonderful public viewing platform, but also because of the amazing speed of the elevator - 25,2 km/h. I think the speed of the two elevators for visitors is limited to 18 km/h, but it's still very fast.

Which is the fastest public elevator in the world?

Comment: I'm gonna be in Frankfurt tomorrow. I guess I'll be going up there then :-) I see it costs 5€.

Comment: The weather is cold, and on the top of the tower is really cold, so wear warm clothes!

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. Fast elevators can be a tourist attraction by their nature of being something extreme, certainly if it's the very fastest. Being a tourist attraction, they should be on-topic on this site.

Comment: Regarding the on-topicness, see also [this discussion on meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1008/2509).

Comment: Oddly, despite my dislike for factoid questions, I like this one. It's the kind of thing that if I discovered it was nearby and not famous I might go check it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The worlds fastest elevator: [Burj Khalifa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burj_Khalifa) with 64 km per hour

Though, the speed of the elevator to the observation deck is [36 km per hour](http://www.burjkhalifa.ae/observation-deck/at-the-top-experience.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Taipei 101 elevator]

Burj Khalifa might have beaten it recently, but until last year (when I visited Taiwan) the record was held by Taipei 101's elevators - which at a speed of 1010 m/min or 60km/hr are pretty damn fast too! It's shoots up so fast that it makes your ears pop due to the pressure difference.

Answer (score 4):

[Taipei 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei_101) observatory elevator hits 60.6km/h. The elevator gets fully pressurized before it starts moving and it's incredibly fast to get up there. You can take it by simply purchasing a ticket at the base of the building. I would recommend a crystal clear day to go up there as the visibility is often a problem.

Bonus read: The view from there is not mind blowing (not sure if it's worth the price of the ticket) but they do have some nice glass/mirror effects looking down through the building. The best view of the city is free (as in free beer) from the 'Elephant mountain' (easy) hike trail at the outskirt of the city (Xiangshan station).

Answer (score 0):

The [CN Tower in Toronto](http://www.cntower.ca/en-CA/Plan-Your-Visit/Attractions/High-Speed-Elevators.html) seems pretty good too: 22 km per hour